# Unable to use external types in my d.ts file

Tags: typescript

I want to have all my TS interfaces declared in one d.ts file, like this:

```
interface Iface1 {
   testMethod(): Observable<string>;
}
```

However, when I try to use external type (here is an 'Observable' from rxjs) compiler is unable to resolve what 'Observable' is.

Adding line:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/rxjs/observable.d.ts" />
```

to the top of the file does not seem to help at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import the Observable type in your interfaces d.ts file:

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/rxjs/observable.d.ts" />

import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
```

Getting Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'? 
Make sure your tsconfig.json has the moduleResolution set to "node":

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Here is an example how to import interface:

**MyInterfaces.ts**

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/rxjs/observable.d.ts" />

import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

export interface IFoo {
    bar: Observable<number>;
}
```

**App.ts**

```
import { IFoo } from "./MyInterfaces"

var myVar : IFoo = {
    bar: null
}
```

[Further read on Typescript modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Modules.md)

Comment: I tried that, but then Iface1 is not visible to any other .ts file.

Comment: @Azargoth, I've added an example showing how to use your interface.

Comment: Ok, it seems it's impossible to use d.ts file with an "import" statement as a global definition file, so it must be imported explicitly. One way or another, problem solved.